# incrementing negatively in a for loop does not provide the correct answer

Tags: python

Given the following code which counts positively for set A and negatively for set B . Set A works as expected but set B gives `0` as answer instead of `-2`. Why is that ?

```
arr = [1,3,2,12]
A = set([1,3,5])
B = set([1,3,5])

def func(arr,A,B):
    countA = 0
    countB = 0
    for i in arr:
        if i in A:
            countA += 1
        elif i in B:
            countB -= 1

    return countA
```

Returns 2. But....

```
arr = [1,3,2,12]
A = set([1,3,5])
B = set([1,3,5])

def func(arr,A,B):
    countA = 0
    countB = 0
    for i in arr:
        if i in A:
            countA += 1
        elif i in B:
            countB -= 1

    return countB
```

Returns 0

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `elif` to `if`. Since it's an `elif`, once an item is found in A it's not checked in B and since all the `arr` numbers that exist in B are also in A you get 0. Just:

```
def func(arr,A,B):
    countA = 0
    countB = 0
    for i in arr:
        if i in A:
            countA += 1
        if i in B:
            countB -= 1

    return countA, countB
```

Comment: oh thanks, I did not know `elif` does not run if `if` is `True`

Comment: Yes, it's a short for `else if`

Comment: I thought using two `if` is wrong. Or at least bad styling.

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini two `if`s is perfectly acceptable if it reflects the desired logic of your program.  For the conditions `i in A` and `i in B`, they each have their own distinct code to run when true, and it is possible for both conditions to be true, neither condition to be true, or either condition to be true.  This necessitates 2 `if` statements.  Using an `if`/`elif` series would require at least 3 conditions and redundant code to accomplish the same thing